# Possible to add a fillet on the inside of this mesh?

Tags: edit-mode

I have the following drainage tray for printing but I would like to add a fillet on the highlighted edges so as to minimize leakages.
I have tried beveling on this selection of edges via `ctrl b` but unfortunately does not produce desired results.

[image]
Any ideas?

Comment: All the triangles will cause problems

Comment: How much does preserving the exact shape matter? If you're open to (slight) modifications, you could select the base (bottom) face(s), extrude them very slightly on the Z axis, then scale inwards slightly as well. It will help you create the shape of a "beveled lip" (despite the triangulated sides), but it will increase the height of the object slightly (unless you do something else to mitigate this).

Comment: hmmm.. ok I will try that and get back to you.  In the mean time  I deleted the vertical tria's and hid the bottom surface and then I selected the edges (ie, the highlighted edges in picture). At this point, is there a way to merge them to leave one edge? Then I could extrude on z axis?

Comment: Hmmm, not sure. Will selecting ithe whole "ring" and pressing M (merge) and selecting "By Distance" help? Have an undo step ready, though because the density of your verts may cause some (wanted ones) to get deleted unintentionally (depending on the size of your mesh - it's hard to tell from the image).

Comment: The merge by distance helped me create a bevel feature but unfortunately I ran into another problem when attempting to slice it for printing. Thanks anyhow for the new ideas.